# Error when creating new Nativescript and Angular shared project

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to create a new project of Nativescript using the shared project option. However, as soon as I run ng new I have this error on the terminal:

> An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
> See "/private/..../angular-errors.log" for further details.

This is the command I'm running:

```
ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics my-shared-app --shared --style=scss
```

And this is the version of my packages:

- MacBook Air m1
- Node v16.13.0
- Npm v8.1.0
- NS v8.1.5
- Angular CLI 13.1.2

I've followed all the steps to install and create like said in the docs here: https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project

When creating projects with `ns`everything works just fine. I can create the project, develop, test and run `ins run android/iOS`. For example, this command works:

```
ns create HelloWorld --template @nativescript/template-hello-world-ts
```

Any idea what's going on with this error?

Comment: same problem here trying to add nativescript/schematics to an existing angular v13 project

Comment: @Rebolon it seems that those schematics are out of date. [Nativescript itself is recommending](https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/index.html) using Nx for that purpose.

Comment: @celsomtrindate thanx i've seen this, but i'm not satisfied with the fact of adding a new item  in the stack only to be able to share code between web and native. No solution for instance, and a bit sad.

Answer (score 3):

I think `nativescript/schematics` is no longer supported in nativescript 8. I tried this 2 months ago, and wasn't successful in using `nativescript/schematics` with {N}8. Their recommendation as appears [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/index.html) is to use other solutions such as [Nrwl Nx DevTools](https://nx.dev/) code-sharing platform, that is used for code-sharing in monorepos. Their two recommendations are using it [with @nativescript/nx](https://github.com/NativeScript/nx) or with [@nstudio/xplat](https://nstudio.io/xplat)).

Here are 2 more links from my previous research, by Nathan Walker (one of the creators of nativescript) explaining how to use code sharing with xplat:
[xplat multi-platform tools for Nx workspaces with Nathan Walker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0I8D25nab5c&t=121s)

And a newer one for [sharing code with NativeScript and Capacitor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHcL_UbnnPY) (the Ionic wrapper).